# Why did my Jekyll site suddenly stop creating paths/index.html for permalinks?

Tags: web, jekyll

Today, I ran `jekyll build` on my same ol' web folder, and got a different result than ever before.

I would expect Jekyll to build paths with an index.html file in each, as specified by my **_config.yml** file:

```
permalink: /:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title
```

In the past, this has always resulted in a file like:

```
/the-category/2015/01/01/the-title/index.html
```

However instead of the expected behavior, today Jekyll built out each of the permalink paths ending in a .html file, like:

```
/the-category/2015/01/01/the-title.html
```

What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the newest version of Jekyll interprets my same ol' **_config.yml** file differently. I simply needed to add the trailing slash to my `permalink` definition:

```
permalink: /:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title/
```

And now everything is back to normal.